# Cloud IAP and CORS

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cors

I am using Cloud IAP to protect APIs (on Google App Engine), and I'd like to access them from a JavaScript app in the browser.

The problem is: the browser tries to send a preflight `OPTIONS` request, which is blocked by IAP. As I cannot attach any `Authorization` header to `OPTIONS`, what is the solution?

Comment: The solution is to make the server allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests. The CORS protocol requires that. Or else change your API to use some authentication/credentials mechanism other than the Authorization request header.

Comment: This is the thing: how do we tell Cloud IAP to allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests?

Comment: This is not supported yet by Cloud IAP, but there is an open feature request ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78326322

Comment: This feature is now available: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing